# select2 does not show the results received from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4, ui-select2

Where is the error?

My `select2` box doesn't show results received from `ajax` call, it says - The results could not be loaded.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<select class="airportList form-control" name="From_1"> 
 <option disabled selected>Going from</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $(".airportList").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    // data: [{id:'ADL',text:'Adelaide, Australia, ADL'},{id:'MEL',text:'Melbourne, Australia, MEL'}],
    ajax: {
      type: "GET",
      url: "data.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        return {
          q: params.term, // search term
          page: params.page
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results: data
        };
      }
    }
  });
});
```

data.php (that I receive):

```
[
{id:'ADL',text:'Adelaide, Australia, ADL'},
{id:'MEL',text:'Melbourne, Australia, MEL'}
]
```

Comment: What is select2()? A custom function, as it seems? When making the ajax call you can display the result using something else than oprocessResults like `.always(function(response) {
console.log(response[0].id ) });`

Comment: Select2 is a well-known JS plugin to add multiselect input fields

Comment: No, `select2()` is a function from `select2` [project](https://select2.github.io/). I didn't understand how to `console.log` the result? I see that the result of the request comes to browser but it seems like it doesn't get proceeded properly by the function.

Comment: Anyways, you know what I mean... Here is the solution (see answer)

Comment: Where is the answer?:)

Comment: posted below, basically you should use input instead of select for ajax

Comment: I would check your network connections on  your browser to see what kind of request was made, if any. From there you can get a clue where to proceed: if it was your code or just the server's response.

Comment: @ВикторЕрмаков I updated the answer with an example. I think the `processResults` method needs to be adjusted for your code to work. Select2 had been updated, so select or input apparently work now

Comment: @PaulJeromeBordallo I see that GET request is received via Network (when I type "a", data.php?q=a is received with the content: [{id:'ADL',text:'Adelaide, Australia, ADL'},{id:'MEL',text:'Melbourne, Australia, MEL'}]. But still it doesn't appear on the `select2` box.

Comment: @SamBattat Previously I mapped the received data but even like this in my case it doesn't work. I ran out of ideas what can be the reason...

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, here is an updated answer:

```
processResults: function(data) {
  return {
    results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
      return {
        id: obj.id,
        text: obj.text
      };
    })
  };
}
```

This part is where you have the issue I think.
See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jes0wrka/

Comment: In my case when result is returned this function wasn't even called. Why?

Comment: Thi helped me to get the data since my json returns many other params, with custom names... but i can't select the resulting data, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just include the [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
let res = JSON.parse(data);
```

The code like:

```
$(".airportList").select2({
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  ajax: {
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
      let res = JSON.parse(data);
      return {
        results: res
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem in my case was that the format of the `JSON` from data.php file was INCORRECT!!!:

```
[
{id:'ADL',text:'Adelaide, Australia, ADL'},
{id:'MEL',text:'Melbourne, Australia, MEL'}
]
```

The CORRECT JSON should be:

```
[
{"id":"ADL","text":"Adelaide, Australia, ADL"},
{"id":"MEL","text":"Melbourne, Australia, MEL"}
]
```